# How to get all users from Kinvey

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kinvey

I'm makind simple ReactJS app, and I use Kinvey for back end as a service. What URL do i need to get all users form Kinvey data?

Answer (score 2):

You can get all users from your application by making `GET` request to `https://baas.kinvey.com/user/APP_KEY/` You will need one of thease

- `Basic` headers `{"Authorization" : "Basic btoa(username+password)"}`
- `Kinvey` headers `{"Authorization" : "Kinvey authtoken"}`

Answer (score 1):

Please also see [Kinvey (Android) - I need all users list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938051/kinvey-android-i-need-all-users-list)

You cannot get all users from any front-end app.